# C++ How to make template<T>f() return -1 for integral T, nullptr for pointer-type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, return-type, sfinae

I need to accomplish the following:

```
template<typename T>
f() {
    :
    return { -1 if T is of integral type, else nullptr }
}
```

In my particular use case, T could be one of four types:

```
int
Py_ssize_t  // ssize_t
Py_hash_t   // ssize_t

PyObject*   // PyObject is some C struct
```

This is the best solution I have so far:

```
template<typename T>
T test(typename enable_if<is_integral<T>::value, void*>::type = nullptr)
{ return -1; }

template<typename T>
T test(typename enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, void*>::type = nullptr)
{ return nullptr; }
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/yU3mj4)

But is this using a sledgehammer to crack a nut?

My only objection is that it solves a wider problem scope, but I'm not sure whether it is complete without additional fiddling with std::decay.

I make a habit of resisting the temptation to complexify code so that it can also solve imaginary extensions of the problem scope at hand.

But in this case I can't see a simpler solution.

Comment: I see no problem in your solution. C++ type_traits often resemble a giant sledgehammer...

Comment: If there are only three possible types (`int`, `ssize_t`, `PyObject*`), why not just write three overloads for those types?

Comment: @delnan, I did try overloading, but hit a "functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded" error.

Comment: You can however add two or three explicit specializations.

Comment: @MSalters, would you care to put this as an answer? (Or would anyone else? So that the various solution paths can be seen side-by-side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lot clearer if you put the `enable_if` on the return type:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_integral<T>::value, T>::type
test() {
    return -1;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type
test() {
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I think the second case is more properly written using the original `is_pointer`.

Comment: This is definitely cleaner, thanks. A couple of things, maybe replace "you NEED to ..." With "BETTER to..." seeing as the original does compute, also would it not be more poetic to put T as the second argument to enable_if?

Answer (score 4):

Don't over-think this. You can simply use:

```
template<typename T>
T f() { return std::is_integral<T>::value ? T(-1) : T(0); }
```

This works even with the `T(-1)` conversion if `T` is a pointer type, because that conversion could only be undefined at run-time, not at compile-time, but at run-time is never actually gets executed.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. `-1` may be improperly aligned as a `int*`, for instance.

Comment: @T.C. deref is not undefined either. Its result is. More precisey, that pointer is probably referencing protected memory area which results in an access violation when dereferenced.

Comment: Edited to say "could" instead of "would" to hopefully avoid that discussion. It doesn't really matter here whether it's undefined, only that if it's undefined, it's still not a problem.

Comment: *+1* For the solution I wanted to post :D

Comment: I think `T(0)` fails for `T=void*`, `(T)0` seems to work. `return (T)(std::is_integral<T>::value ? -1 : 0)`

Comment: @Pi `T(0)` is perfectly valid for `T=void*`, and means the same thing as `(T)0`. As for casting the result of `?:`, that's a bad idea, C++ now only treats an integer literal with a value of zero as a null pointer constant, not any arbitrary integer constant expression with a value of zero, so your modified version is no longer guaranteed to result in a null pointer if T is a pointer type.

Comment: @hvd: I think the objection is correct, for `T=void*` the "expression" `void*(0)` is ill-formed. Same problem as `long long(0)` : you can't have a token sequence naming the type.

Comment: @MSalters Template arguments aren't like macros, they're more like typedefs in that respect. After `#define T void*` or `#define T long long`, `T(0)` is indeed an error, but after `typedef void* T;` or `typedef long long T;`, `T(0)` is perfectly valid. And in a template instantiation with `T=void*`, `T(0)` is just as valid as the typedef version.

Comment: @hvd: Indeed. Template compilation doesn't work by token substitution.

Answer (score 3):

By request, for the given types it can be simplified to

```
template<typename T>
T f() { return -1; }

template<>
PyObject* f<PyObject*>() { return nullptr; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T>
T f2(std::true_type /* is integral */){return -1;}
template<class T>
T f2(std::false_type /* is integral */){return nullptr;}
template<class T>
T f(){ return f2(std::is_integral<T>{}); }
```

when in doubt, tag dispatch.

You can hide `f2` in a details namespace.

This gets rid of the SFINAE noise.

If you want SFINAE failure on bad types, you can do some decltype and auto and chain to `f3` which tests for pointer types.  Still less spammy.